# Is multiple entry for UK general tourist visa possible?

Tags: visas, uk, london, multiple-entry, filipino-citizens

I am a Filipina. I booked a tour package with Expat Explore for 10 days tour in Europe. But the start and end point of the tour will be in Greenwich. Basically, I will enter London on June 1, then leave with the tour group to Paris on June 2. Then return to Greenwich on June 11 after the tour.My flight back home will be on June 12. So that means I will enter twice in London.

I want to know if UK Visa is good for multiple entry or single entry only?

Comment: What does your visa say? Single or Multiple entry?